# Using a Foreach without VBA - entering it as a formula

Tags: excel

I can not find a formulat that multiplies chances the way i want.
I can not use additional cells or VBA because this is a company excel sheet that is locked to a certain format.

Here is some pseudocode that illustrates what i want to do;

```
value oneminus(value) //typeof delegate
{
    return 1 - value;
}

value ProductDelegate(range, delegate)
{
    Result result = 1;
    foreach value in range
    {
        result *= delegate(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

What i would want to call is a prefabricated version of the `ProductDelegate`. I would call it like so `=ProductDelegate(J56:J73, "1-"&J)`. I do not think that `ProductDelegate` actually exists so i feel like what i am asking is not implemented in excel. Are there any options for this particular usecase? Any statistics function i am missing?

Comment: Sorry - it was late - the title is in german... i will fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this. Just type the following formula but hold down CTRL-SHFT when hitting enter:

```
=PRODUCT(1-J56:J73)
```